# Phalcon: Model relationships with Namespaces

Tags: model, namespaces, phalcon, magic-function

I'm just trying to set up models with namespaces.  That part's simple.  It's the relationship part that I'm having a tough time with.

I have these two models (these are stripped down):

```
<?php

namespace My\App\V1\Models;

class Movies extends \My\Namespace\Path\Base
{
}

?>



<?php

namespace My\App\V1\Models

class Genres extends \My\Namespace\Path\Base
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Movies', 'genre_id');
    }

    public function howManyMovies()
    {
        return $this->countMovies();
    }
}

?>
```

So... as is, this will give me:

```
Cannot redeclare class My\App\V1\Models\Movies ....
```

So, I started thinking it has something to do with namespaces.  So...  I change the hasMany to:

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'My\\App\\V1\\Models\\Movies', 'genre_id');
```

I can put backslashes in front of the "My" or not, but either way I then get:

```
The method "countMovies" doesn't exist on model "My\App\V1\Models\Genres"
```

I try changing that line to:

```
return $this->countMyAppV1ModelsMovies();
```

... which is rather verbose, but whatever.  I still get a "method doesn't exist" error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.  After much time of trying to figure this out, then 5 minutes after posting, I get it....

One must use an alias:

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'My\\App\\V1\\Models\\Movies', 'genre_id', ['alias'=>'Movies']);
```

I'll leave this here for anyone else who may need it.

Comment: This is exactly what I've faced today. Thank you. For anyone else, try this, it works

Comment: It took me hours to figure that out! I did the same for every hasMany, belongsTo and hasManyToMany and it fixed all my problems :)